# Monthly results for each employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to get data that will give results for all my employees monthly, so the final result set will have a month column and then the employee in that month.

I've put together the year to date range in so far but I'm stuck how to get the result desired.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE,
       AVG(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= @StartDate AND SaleDate < @EndDate Then BonusImpactScore END)
FROM Sales
WHERE SaleDate >=@StartDate AND SaleDate < @EndDate
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE
```

What can i do to get a month breakdown and all employees in that month.

My desired outcome would look like;

[image]

Comment: You would start this by providing the table definition, sample data and desired output.

Comment: I've added desired result, the sample data just has multiple scores for an employee that I would be looking to average for that month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
select employee, year(saledate), month(saledate), avg(BonusImpactScore)
from t
where SaleDate >=@StartDate and SaleDate < @EndDate
group by employee, year(saledate), month(saledate);
```